# How to read and write to a Temenos T24 application using JMeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, testng, load-testing, performance-testing

i am trying to perform a load test on a temenos T24 application ascertain  the performance of the application using JMeter. It uses servlets which makes impossible to go to other pages because its fully javascript based. I am hoping the gurus would help me out .
Thanks in Advance.
Regards, 
Benjamin.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the BrowserServlet of T24 using jmeter. All the transactions of t24 is handled through browser servlet. Try capturing a login and logoff action using jmeter proxy, filter everything apart from the browserservlet (filter even the javascripts), replay the script, you should be able to get the response from T24.

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer please?

Comment: Please check the following link https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html
There are several good tutorials about jmeter in the Jmeter website itself

Comment: After following the steps, getting Error Message : SECURITY VIOLATION (Code: SV-06). Can you help?

Comment: Security violation is a global error message from T24 and there could be several reasons behind it(session ids, window names, tokens, counters etc). Please check the browser logs for more information.

Answer (score -3):

T24 is not a JavaEE web application, even it can be accessed via web. The named JBasic is major programming language. You should access background terminal to check routine(E.g. Shh tool). But I suggest you first read helptext in T24, if you understand what's the APPLICATION, VERSION and FUNCTION, and then you could be batter understand T24. Good luck!

Comment: This comment is completely wrong and misleading.  The OP never asked anything about JBasic (which by the way is wrong too, just like "Shh tool" is too), nor did they ask anything about applications versions and functions which refers to a completely different area of the system.